# SBJson returning nil causing cocoa window to not show up

Tags: cocoa, json

I'm using the example [here](http://blog.zachwaugh.com/post/309924609/how-to-use-json-in-cocoaobjective-c).  If there isn't a value for the key, my application returns `-[NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: attempt to insert nil` in the console, and my window doesn't show up.  How could I preform a check to make sure this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test whether the object pointer is `nil`:

```
if (theObject != nil) {
    [myArray insertObject:theObject atIndex:idx];
} else {
    //The pointer is nil. This probably means the JSON framework gave you an error object (assuming you enabled it to), in which case, now's probably the time to present it.
    if (error != nil)
        [NSApp presentError:error];
}
```